# how to allow AWS IOT python SDK to talk to multiple `Things`

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I am able to communicate with single `Thing` via Python SDK by downloading `AWS connection kit`. following below steps;

from AWS account > Services > AWS IOT > onboard > Get started > click `get started`, Select Linux VM and Python SDK, click NEXT;

The first steps after this is `Choose a thing`, where I can only select single thing. Which means that the connection kit that I will get will only be able to talk to that single thing. Is there any way I could get single certificate that allows my python script to publish and subscribe to multiple things by providing things ARN end-points ?

```
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish("arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:thing/Thing1", "topic_1", "Hello thing 1")
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish("arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:thing/Thing2", "topic_1", "Hello thing 2")
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish("arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:thing/Thing3", "topic_1", "Hello thing 3")
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What is your usecase?

Comment: I want to control and monitor multiple `things` from single python script.

Comment: The quality of the answers you will receive here has usually a direct relation to the quality of the question and how many details are included.

Comment: Sure, you can create an IoT certificate policy that lets you talk on any topic.